# Which algorithm for finding empty ranges of numbers in a range of numbers?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, range

I'm doing some file analysis, where I mark explored regions in the file.  Now I would like to find the *un*explored regions, so I know what to look at next. This is much like what defragmentation software shows for free and used regions.

**Example:**

In this picture, let's say that explored regions are red, unexplored regions are gray. I need to determine the gray-region boundaries from these red regions.

[image]

**My current code, a custom binary reader that logs what's been read:**

```
public class CustomBinaryReader : BinaryReader {

    private readonly List<Block> _blocks;

    public CustomBinaryReader([NotNull] Stream input) : this(input, Encoding.Default) { }

    public CustomBinaryReader(Stream input, Encoding encoding, bool leaveOpen = true) : base(input, encoding, leaveOpen) {
        _blocks = new List<Block>();
    }

    public override byte[] ReadBytes(int count) {
        Log(count);
        return base.ReadBytes(count);
    }

    private void Log(int count) {
        _blocks.Add(new Block(BaseStream.Position, count));
    }

    private IEnumerable<Block> GetUnreadBlocks() {
        // how to get unread blocks in the stream, from read blocks ?
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the type that defines what a region is:

```
public class Block {
    public Block(long position, long length) {
        Position = position;
        Length = length;
    }

    public long Position { get; }
    public long Length { get; }
}
```

**Question:**

Is there a class of algorithms or data structures to solve such problem (like a tree or a graph) ?  If such thing does not exist, can you give me some approach or tips on how to solve such problem?

Comment: Based on the image or the raw data?

Comment: It will be based on a struct with two members: `position` and `length`

Comment: Please update the question with the actual data structure you're using to store the data so people can help

Comment: I don't see the difficulty here.  You have the raw data, right?  You sort the list of used blocks, merge adjacent blocks, and then use the remaining boundaries as the boundaries of your empty areas.

Comment: Hold on let me edit my question a bit.

Comment: If you have an answer, it's better to post it as an answer rather than editing it into the question, even if it is based on an answer already posted.

Comment: Yes, done, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the used areas in order of position.
Find the upper bound of each as `position+length`.
From there, each open area starts at the upper bound of one area, until (but not including) the lower bound of the next.

Answer (score 1):

From **@Prune**'s answer, here's the full implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using JetBrains.Annotations;

namespace Whatever
{
    public sealed class LoggedBinaryReader : BinaryReader
    {
        [UsedImplicitly]
        public LoggedBinaryReader([NotNull] Stream input) : this(input, Encoding.Default)
        {
        }

        public LoggedBinaryReader(Stream input, Encoding encoding, bool leaveOpen = true) : base(input, encoding, leaveOpen)
        {
            Journal = new LoggedBinaryReaderJournal(this);
        }

        private LoggedBinaryReaderJournal Journal { get; }

        public override int Read()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.Read();
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.Read(buffer, index, count);
        }

        public override int Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.Read(buffer, index, count);
        }

        public override char ReadChar()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadChar();
        }

        public override char[] ReadChars(int count)
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadChars(count);
        }

        public override string ReadString()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadString();
        }

        public override bool ReadBoolean()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadBoolean();
        }

        public override byte ReadByte()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadByte();
        }

        public override sbyte ReadSByte()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadSByte();
        }

        public override short ReadInt16()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadInt16();
        }

        public override int ReadInt32()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadInt32();
        }

        public override long ReadInt64()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadInt64();
        }

        public override ushort ReadUInt16()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadUInt16();
        }

        public override uint ReadUInt32()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadUInt32();
        }

        public override ulong ReadUInt64()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadUInt64();
        }

        public override byte[] ReadBytes(int count)
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadBytes(count);
        }

        public override float ReadSingle()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadSingle();
        }

        public override double ReadDouble()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadDouble();
        }

        public override decimal ReadDecimal()
        {
            using (new LoggedBinaryReaderScope(Journal))
                return base.ReadDecimal();
        }

        public IEnumerable<LoggedBinaryReaderRegion> GetRegionsRead()
        {
            return Journal.GetRegions();
        }

        public IEnumerable<LoggedBinaryReaderRegion> GetRegionsUnread()
        {
            var blocks = new LinkedList<LoggedBinaryReaderRegion>(Journal.GetRegions());

            var curr = blocks.First;

            // nothing explored
            if (curr == null)
            {
                yield return new LoggedBinaryReaderRegion(0, BaseStream.Length);
                yield break;
            }

            // account for beginning of file
            if (curr.Value.Position > 0)
                yield return new LoggedBinaryReaderRegion(0, curr.Value.Position);

            // in-between
            while (true)
            {
                var next = curr.Next;
                if (next == null)
                    break;

                var position = curr.Value.Position + curr.Value.Length;
                var length = next.Value.Position - position;

                if (length > 0)
                    yield return new LoggedBinaryReaderRegion(position, length);

                curr = next;
            }

            // account for end of file
            if (curr.Value.Position + curr.Value.Length < BaseStream.Length)
                yield return new LoggedBinaryReaderRegion(
                    curr.Value.Position + curr.Value.Length,
                    BaseStream.Length - (curr.Value.Position + curr.Value.Length));
        }
    }

    public struct LoggedBinaryReaderRegion
    {
        internal LoggedBinaryReaderRegion(long position, long length)
        {
            Position = position;
            Length = length;
        }

        public long Position { get; }

        public long Length { get; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{nameof(Position)}: {Position}, {nameof(Length)}: {Length}";
        }
    }

    internal class LoggedBinaryReaderJournal
    {
        internal LoggedBinaryReaderJournal([NotNull] LoggedBinaryReader reader)
        {
            if (reader == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reader));

            Reader = reader;
            Regions = new List<LoggedBinaryReaderRegion>();
        }

        private long Position { get; set; }

        private LoggedBinaryReader Reader { get; }

        private List<LoggedBinaryReaderRegion> Regions { get; }

        internal void StartLogging()
        {
            Position = Reader.BaseStream.Position;
        }

        internal void StopLogging()
        {
            var length = Reader.BaseStream.Position - Position;
            var region = new LoggedBinaryReaderRegion(Position, length);
            Regions.Add(region);
        }

        public IEnumerable<LoggedBinaryReaderRegion> GetRegions()
        {
            return Regions.OrderBy(s => s.Position);
        }
    }

    internal struct LoggedBinaryReaderScope : IDisposable
    {
        private LoggedBinaryReaderJournal Journal { get; }

        internal LoggedBinaryReaderScope(LoggedBinaryReaderJournal journal)
        {
            Journal = journal;
            Journal.StartLogging();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Journal.StopLogging();
        }
    }
}
```

**What this does:**

It records whatever `BinaryReader` reads and can return regions that have been read or not. Every `Read...` method is recorded by a journal.

Actually I needed this for an old video game obscure format for which I wrote a parser, browsing +300Kb of data in a hex-editor with weird structs just to ensure I've read the whole file was overkill, this `LoggedBinaryReader` instantly told me what I've eventually missed :)